# Geany - preserve folding and unfolding of text every time a document is opened

Tags: code, geany

Whenever I open a file in the Geany IDE, I want the file's text to be folded in exactly the same way that the text was folded the last time I was editing it. Is it possible to configure Geany to keep the code folding consistent between editing sessions?

Comment: If this cannot yet be done in Geany, I would like to know whether any other text editor has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Geany does not have such a feature (unless it has been added recently and not included in latest LTS-version). Yet, there is a plugin called [geanynumberedbookmarks](http://plugins.geany.org/geanynumberedbookmarks.html) that claims to be able to do this. Also, assuming that I don't remember wrong, [Kate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_%28text_editor%29) has this ability builtin.